# why does this page redirect in a loop? (simple session login page)

Tags: php, session, redirect, post

Ok ive asked this question on here today but this code is much easier to follow. i still dont understand why this page would redirect in a loop?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start();
$_SESSION['passw'] = "word";
$_POST['passw'] = "word";

if($_POST['passw'] === "word" ){
echo 'post ok';
$_SESSION['passw'] = "word";
unset($_POST);
session_write_close();
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
if($_SESSION['passw'] === "word") {

echo 'password checked ok<br>';

}

?>
```

Comment: You are setting `$_POST['passw'] ` to "word" and then redirecting with header() back to the page.

Comment: why do you have header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) after an echo statement?

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's show just the relevant lines:

```
$_POST['passw'] = "word";
if($_POST['passw'] === "word" ){
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

Basically you are saying

```
 if (true) {
     reloadThePage();
 }
```

Comment: You explained it better even though I beat you to the answer +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are setting the value to "word" immediately before your IF statement.

```
$_POST['passw'] = "word";

if($_POST['passw'] === "word" ){
```

So, to fix, remove this:

```
$_POST['passw'] = "word";
```